# Rewrite Wordpress' Blog Archive URL structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently, my website's archive page lists are displaying as:

> example.com/2012/05

I would like to change the url structure to:

> example.com/blog/2012/05

I've tried using Redirects in combination with rewrites but I am not sure that works well.
I've also just tried to do a simple rewrite like

> RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /blog/$1/$2 [L]

to capture /year/month urls and convert them but I am unsuccessful.

I know how to edit the archive navigation menu to prepend a blog/ before the rest of the url, but I can't get this rewrite to link to the page properly

It is not in a subfolder. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **real easy** way to do this...

Under the SETTINGS > PERMALINKS, change

```
  /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

to

```
  /blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

**Note** that your homepage will not be on /blog/. If you wanted that you will need to create a page called 'Blog' and change your 'Posts page' under SETTINGS > READING, to the 'Blog' page you created. More on that here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Thank you, but I have this set up already.

All posts go to blog/category/postname

It's just that the archives:
BLOG ARCHIVES
May 2012
April 2012
March 2012

go to the url's /year/month/ and I would like it to be /blog/year/month

Thank you