# Insert URL-structure to widget archive

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Is there a solution for how to insert URL-structure into widget archive?

As it is now, the URL-structure is the following:
-http://example.com/2012

I want it to be:
-http://example.com/**sub**/2012

The docs for the function is this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives but no where t be found is statement for changing the URL-structure. Maybe there is a work around?

The code is the following:

```
function set_widget_archives_type($args) {
    $args = array(
        'type' => 'yearly',
    );
    return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_archives_args','set_widget_archives_type');
```

Comment: It was much easier than I thought. Just followed this example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917371/rewrite-wordpress-blog-archive-url-structure

Comment: if you found your answer in another stackoverflow question, either delete this question (since it hasn't got any answers), or provide your solution as an answer to yourself and accept it.